# Restrict access | change template or redirect based on user role

Tags: laravel, acl

I have AdminLTE on laravel application and when admin user logins through AdminLte login screen, he logins to admin panel and accesses its pages. It's ok, when he opens frontend website, admin name shows on the header (as shown on below image) as he logins previously through admin login screen.

[image]

What I want he must not be login on front site pages. (The following should  appear on the header as shown on below image).

[image]

He needs to  login separately on front site. What's the solution for that.

Comment: I consider it that you want user to login on front website and admin to log in using admin login page if that is the case you need to do multi-auth, you need 2 separate guards one for admin and one for user, guard will protect admin to access user pages and user to access admin pages

Comment: @dollar OK, How to make guards. Can you write an answer

Comment: @dollar , In my case the admin can access the front end website pages but he must not be login at front website

Comment: It would be better you update your question with your code, need to check what exactly you are doing?

Comment: @dollar, I have ellaborate each thing in question

Comment: Need to check your routes and middleware, to find out what you have done and where it is going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using something like Entrust? It comes with all the middlewares you need to restrict and redirect based on user roles and permissions. Examples: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/blob/master/README.md#middleware

Comment: @yahyazini, I am not restricting users. My problem is not to restrict and redirect users.

Answer (score 1):

ok so you have to make if and else on app.blade.php from where your menu is generated.

```
 @if (!Auth::guest())
    @include('admin.includes.normal_header')
 @endif
```

Comment: Ok let me try, I have to put this if else on my front website layout page

Comment: So in that case the admin user still logins on front end website?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two middleware, one is admin middleware, another one is for normal login user.
In normal middleware, you can check if the user is logged in as an admin or not.if logged as an admin in then logged out him.

Comment: According to your answer if I logout admin then he still remains login to admin panel?

Comment: No, the Admin will be logged out entirely.

Comment: I want that he stills remains lonin to admin panel

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to overcome this:

1. you can use different guards and middleware( using separate table for admin and user)
2. you can use role based permission( if you use users table for both types of user)

Step - 1: create a roles table ( cols: id, role ) and a `Role.php` Model
Step - 2: add a column named `'role_id'` at your user table
Step - 3: make a relationship for role and user on your `User.php` model
           user belongs to a role

// Assuming that you have 2 roles: `1->Admin`, `2->User`

```
public function role(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

step-3: in you nav, use the if else condition

```
     @if (!Auth::guest())
          @if(auth()->user()->role()->id == 1)
              @include('admin.admin_header_nav')
          @else
              @include('user.normal_header_nav')
          @endif        
     @endif


    // you can just use those condition on a link, or create a middleware     
    //called admin to wrap up the condition( auth()->user()->role()->id == 1 ),    
   // leaving it up to you
```